# How can we refer a single person from a group of person in single word?

Tags: synonyms

I need to know can we use any single word which refers to the meaning of intended person. For example, in a shop we can have Salesman and Manager. I need to send a mail to anyone of person. I wish to have a single word which refers to intended person(either Salesman/Manager).

Regards,
Santhanam

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here, or why you want a single word for it. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I need to use it to declare a variable while coding a software. I can use some other variable name for it. Just out of curiosity, I wanted to whether any word available or not.

Comment: @Santhanam I would suggest using **recipient**.

Comment: Please note that “Naming, including naming programming variables/classes” is [off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Also, I'm still not sure what you're asking for; we need to know _why_ you're selecting the specific person to know what to call them. If it's purely to designate an e-mail **recipient,** then why not just call it that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming of variables in software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, I would suggest either phrasing it with the general "To whom it may concern" or with the more direct "Employee."

Answer (score 1):

If your simply want to name a variable and want to (semantically) reference an entire group/one participant of the group for mailing then you should use **recipient**.